# Grid tie inverter power factor

Tags: inverter, power-factor-correction, power-grid

After installing a grid tie inverter (GTI,) the power factor dropped from 1 to .85 over the last week.  My loads are a combination of inductive and resistive.

I have an option of setting my GTI to feed .8 lag or .8 lead.

Which one should I use?

The default setting is unity.

I understand why the drop but what can I do about it?

My utility mandates a PF of .9 at least

Comment: I don't read a problem.

Comment: @andy Now theres one

Comment: It is good to ask. But keep in mind that in a situation like this you can always just try it and see what happens.

Answer (score -1):

Set it to 0.8 lead for improving the overall power factor